# Signal handling in kernel-space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

I've written a program that uses `SIGALRM` and a signal handler.

I'm now trying to add this as a test module within the kernel.
I found that I had to replace a lot of the functions that libc provides with their underlying syscalls..examples being `timer_create` with `sys_timer_create` `timer_settime` with `sys_timer_settime` and so on.

However, I'm having issues with `sigaction`.
Compiling the kernel throws the following error
`arch/arm/mach-vexpress/cpufreq_test.c:157:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'sys_sigaction' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`

I've attached the relevant code block below

```
int estimate_from_cycles() {
    timer_t timer;
    struct itimerspec old;

    struct sigaction sig_action;
    struct sigevent sig_event;
    sigset_t sig_mask;

    memset(&sig_action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sig_action.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sig_action.sa_mask);

    VERBOSE("Blocking signal %d\n", SIGALRM);
    sigemptyset(&sig_mask);
    sigaddset(&sig_mask, SIGALRM);

    if(sys_sigaction(SIGALRM, &sig_action, NULL)) {
            ERROR("Could not assign sigaction\n");
            return -1;
    }

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &sig_mask, NULL) == -1) {
            ERROR("sigprocmask failed\n");
            return -1;
    }

    memset (&sig_event, 0, sizeof (struct sigevent));
    sig_event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sig_event.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
    sig_event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;


    if (sys_timer_create(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &sig_event, &timer)) {
            ERROR("Could not create timer\n");
            return -1;
    }

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sig_mask, NULL) == -1) {
            ERROR("sigprocmask unblock failed\n");
            return -1;
    }

    cycles = 0;
    VERBOSE("Entering main loop\n");

    if(sys_timer_settime(timer, 0, &time_period, &old)) {
            ERROR("Could not set timer\n");
            return -1;
    }

    while(1) {
            ADD(CYCLES_REGISTER, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is such an approach of taking user-space code and changing the calls alone sufficient to run the code in kernel-space?

Comment: No, not really. The environment in which a kernel module has to operate is vastly different than the one in which a user-level program operates, and the names of certain functions that can be called is just the tip of a rather large iceberg...

Comment: what is the right way to do something like signal handling/alarms in kernel-space then?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you make an example how to send a signal to the kernel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is such an approach of taking user-space code and changing the calls
>   alone sufficient to run the code in kernel-space?

Of course not! What are you doing is to call the implementation of a system call directly from kernel space, but there is **not** guarantee that they SYS_function has the same function definition as the system call. The correct approach is to search for the correct kernel routine that does what you need. Unless you are writing a driver or a kernel feature you don't nee to write kernel code. System calls must be only invoked from user space. Their main purpose is to  offer a safe manner to access low level mechanisms offered by an operating system such as File System, Socket and so on.

Regarding signals. You had a **TERRIBLE** idea to try to use signal system calls from kernel space in order to receive a signal. A process sends a signal to another process and signal are meant to be used in user space, so between user space processes. Typically, what happens when you send a signal to another process is that, if the signal is not masked, the receiving process is stopped and the signal handler is executed. Note that in order to achieve this result two switches between user space and kernel space are required.

However, the kernel has its internal tasks which have exactly the same structure of a user space with some differences ( e.g. memory mapping, parent process, etc..). Of course you cannot send a signal from a user process to a kernel thread (imagine what happen if you send a SIGKILL to a crucial component). Since kernel threads have the same structure of user space thread, they can receive signal but its default behaviour is to drop them unless differently specified.

I'd recommend to change you code to try to send a signal from kernel space to user space rather than try to receive one. ( How would you send a signal to kernel space? which pid would  you specify?). This may be a good starting point : http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#toc6

You are having problem with `sys_sigaction` because this is the old definition of the system call. The correct definition should be  `sys_rt_sigaction`.
From the kernel source 3.12  :

```
 #ifdef CONFIG_OLD_SIGACTION
 asmlinkage long sys_sigaction(int, const struct old_sigaction __user *,
                                 struct old_sigaction __user *);
 #endif

 #ifndef CONFIG_ODD_RT_SIGACTION
 asmlinkage long sys_rt_sigaction(int,
                                  const struct sigaction __user *,
                                  struct sigaction __user *,
                                  size_t);
 #endif
```

BTW, you should **not** call any of them, they are meant to be called from user space.

Comment: Most system calls would probably be very similar to their libc implementation, since libc is just wrapping around these. Almost all the system calls that I ended up using had the same signature and the same idea behind the signature. Regarding the signals, I think you misunderstood..I'm not trying to send a signal to the kernel from *userspace*..I'm trying to run a module as part of the kernel that's trying to receive a signal...all within the kernel itself..but I see one difficulty that you correctly raised..what `pid` would I specify..not sure..

Comment: I have correctly understood what you are trying to do and I tried to explain why it is a bad idea. If you want to test signal to kernel space the best and easiest approach is to send them to user space. For this reason, I have pointed out that article.

Answer (score 1):

You're working in kernel space so you should start thinking like you're working in kernel space instead of trying to port a userspace hack into the kernel. If you need to call the `sys_*` family of functions in kernel space, 99.95% of the time, you're already doing something very, very wrong.

Instead of `while (1)`, have it break the loop on a volatile variable and start a thread that simply sleeps and change the value of the variable when it finishes.

I.e.

```
void some_function(volatile int *condition) {
    sleep(x);
    *condition = 0;
}

volatile int condition = 1;
start_thread(some_function, &condition);
while(condition) {
        ADD(CYCLES_REGISTER, 1);
}
```

However, what you're doing (I'm assuming you're trying to get the number of cycles the CPU is operating at) is inherently impossible on a preemptive kernel like Linux without a lot of hacking. If you keep interrupts on, your cycle count will be inaccurate since your kernel thread may be switched out at any time. If you turn interrupts off, other threads won't run and your code will just infinite loop and hang the kernel.

Are you sure you can't simply use the BogoMIPs value from the kernel? It is essentially what you're trying to measure but the kernel does it very early in the boot process and does it right.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Ideally, I should be using the BogoMIPS code, but I've tried going over it multiple times and I never really feel like I understand what is going on. So I decided to write my own piece of code that does something similar..
The reason I stayed away from using conditions was that with my code, I know **exactly** how many cycles the loop takes..I guess I could go over the instruction set figure out the same with the condition as well..

Comment: No, it still could be inaccurate. Don't forget that the kernel can context switch your thread out.